# Interrupted time series with 2 interventions

Tags: r, regression, time-series, segmented-regression

I want to analyse the effect of media coverage on the increased risk of thrombosis associated with combined oral contraceptive use. The peak of media coverage happened in late May 2015. The plot of the data is shown below.

[image]

I assumed awareness of the increased risk would cause the sale/use of the combined pills decreased. However, that downward trend already happened at least 6 months (November 2014) before the media intervention as seen in the second panel of the following plot.

[image]

I don't know what caused the downward trend in November 2014, so I call it the *unknown intervention*.

I only came across examples that showed how to model **one** intervention with a standard regression like this.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is it valid to analyse the data with just one intervention in late May 2015 (the media coverage).
2. If modelling for the media intervention only, should I just restrict the data from June 2014 onwards (to exclude the upward trend from January 2013)?
3. If restrict the data from June 2014, my data points would reduce from 48 to 32. Would 32 data points be sufficient for a valid interrupted time series analysis (ITSA)? What are the minimum data points for ITSA?
4. Must I take into account the *unknown intervention* in November 2014? What would be the regression expression for **two** interventions?